# What is wrong with this method for counting non-white pixels in a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am playing around with canvas.  I wrote this little snippet where I can draw something in the canvas, press run and have it count the number of pixels.  Only the counting doesn't work.  Specifically, every element of context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data is 0.  I saw a previous post with a similar problem, but in that case, it was because the code ran before the image was loaded.  In this case I have rendered the image and can see it on screen.  I would appreciate any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
</div>
<button id="runButton">Run</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
          y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
      }

      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


      function drawPixel(x,y,r,g,b)
      {
        var id = context.createImageData(1,1);
       var d  = id.data;
       d[0]   = r;
       d[1]   = g;
       d[2]   = b;
       d[3]   = 255;
       context.putImageData( id, x, y );  
      } 

        var clicking = false;



    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        clicking = false;
    })

      canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
        clicking = true;
        var p = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        drawPixel(p.x,p.y,0,0,0);
      }, false);

      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
        if(clicking == false) return;
        var p = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        drawPixel(p.x,p.y,0,0,0);
      }, false);

      $("#runButton").click(countPixels);

      function countPixels()
      {
        var nAlive = 0;
        var p = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
        for (var y = 0, i =0 ; y < canvas.height; y++)
            for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++, i+=4)
            {
                if (p[i] != 255 || p[i + 1] != 255 || p[i + 2] != 255) //Not white
                {
                    nAlive++;
                }
            }

        alert(nAlive);
      }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canvas is initially just black transparent pixels, and the pixel drawing is using black non-transparent pixels, so when you count every pixel that isn't white, all will be counted in this case which makes the result correct.

To fix you need to fill the whole canvas with white first. The white you see now is the background of the canvas:

```
context.fillStyle ="#fff";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuc30jnv/)**

Optionally you could just count non-transparent pixels by using index 3 of the pixel, if you don't want to fill first:

```
if (p[i+3]) //a pixel
{
   nAlive++;
}
```

**[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/cuc30jnv/2/)**